# Google Cloud Endpoints : Not able to open http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer behind a proxy network

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, proxy, google-cloud-endpoints

When i am opening `http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer` Eclipse is showing an error-
>

```
com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
[INFO] WARNING: /_ah/api/static/proxy.html: java.io.IOException: Could not fetch URL: https://webapis-discovery.appspot.com/_ah/api/static/proxy.html, error: Received exception executing http method GET against URL https://webapis-discovery.appspot.com/_ah/api/static/proxy.html: Connection to https://webapis-discovery.appspot.com refused
```

Few lines above Eclipse shows an SEVERE error-
>

```
[INFO] SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
[INFO] java.io.IOException: Could not fetch URL: https://webapis-discovery.appspot.com/_ah/api/static/proxy.html, error: Received exception executing http method GET against URL https://webapis-discovery.appspot.com/_ah/api/static/proxy.html: Connection to https://webapis-discovery.appspot.com refused
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:138)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:45)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.fetchResponse(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:417)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getInputStream(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:296)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getResponseCode(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:149)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:36)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
[INFO]  at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.StaticServlet.getStaticContent(StaticServlet.java:58)
[INFO]  at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.StaticServlet.cacheContent(StaticServlet.java:50)
[INFO]  at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.StaticServlet.init(StaticServlet.java:43)
[INFO]  at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

My college has a proxy server, i have already changed the system wide proxy settings and eclipse proxy settings in Window->Preferences->General->Network Connections .
Everything else in Ubuntu works fine except this. Internet is working inside Eclipse too.

Screenshot showing eclipse Network settings -

http://i1282.photobucket.com/albums/a540/saurabh595/Screenshotfrom2014-08-16_zps35144efe.png

When i try using my mobile internet connection(without proxy server) it works sometimes and shows same error otherwise.

I've been trying to solve this by doing many Google Searches and trying many things out, but I just cannot seem to be able to proceed any further. I would very much appreciate any help I can get from this community of professionals.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API explorer is located outside your proxy, exactly in https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/ and when exploring the APIs available from your development server you go to that address. You may check it by putting this address in your browser (in your localhost by adding /_ah/api/explorer) and seeing where it gets redirected to.

Although you have configured your proxy for outgoing connections from your computer to the rest of the Internet, you can't configure your proxy (unless you work in the IT department of your college) to allow connections originating at apis-explorer.appspot.com to be redirected to your computer.

Hence, unless you'll be able to go out directly to the Internet bypassing the proxy or using another network (e.g., from a smart phone), that won't work for you.

Comment: i m not good at networking, but when the request from  https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/ originates to the proxy server,proxy server should redirect it to my computer automatically ? if no, then how is it different from normal https request ?

Comment: No, the request is not redirected. You still have the api-explorer application doing all the work. It just tries to communicate with your localhost to see which APIs are available, but that communication should be blocked by your proxy. Imagine you can't find your mobile phone and you dial the number to know where you left it. The call goes to the external network and should come back to the phone which is close to you, but if the phone can't get any coverage, it won't respond. The proxy is blocking any communication from the outside to the computers behind the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem earlier. After cleaning the project ( **`Project`**`->`**`Clean`** ) everything **worked fine**.

Comment: Can't understand why your comment has been downvoted. I had to do the same thing to get it working! Thanks.